# Tailwind slide over doesn't open as expected

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I'm trying to add the empty slide-over (https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/overlays/slide-overs#component-166f09a503f2e34749daca3d7dc50525) to my layout and to animate it using alpine.js, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why the transition doesn't work as expected.

```
  <div x-data="{ slideOverOpen: false }">
    <div>
      <a href="#" @click="slideOverOpen = true;">
        Open SlideOver
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- SlideOver -->
    <div class="relative z-10" aria-labelledby="slide-over-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true"
         x-show="slideOverOpen"
         x-transition:enter="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
         x-transition:enter-start="translate-x-full"
         x-transition:enter-end="translate-x-0"
         x-transition:leave="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
         x-transition:leave-start="translate-x-0"
         x-transition:leave-end="translate-x-full">  
      <div class="fixed inset-0 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden">
          <div class="pointer-events-none fixed inset-y-0 right-0 flex max-w-full pl-10">
            <!--
              Slide-over panel, show/hide based on slide-over state.

              Entering: "transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                From: "translate-x-full"
                To: "translate-x-0"
              Leaving: "transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                From: "translate-x-0"
                To: "translate-x-full"
            -->
            <div class="pointer-events-auto w-screen max-w-md">
              <div class="flex h-full flex-col overflow-y-scroll bg-white py-6 shadow-xl">
                <div class="px-4 sm:px-6">
                  <div class="flex items-start justify-between">
                    <h2 class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-black" id="slide-over-title">Panel title</h2>
                    <div class="ml-3 flex h-7 items-center">
                      <button type="button" class="rounded-md bg-white text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
                              @click="slideOverOpen = false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Close panel</span>
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                        </svg>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="relative mt-6 flex-1 px-4 sm:px-6">
                  Content goes here ....
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have extracted my code here: https://codepen.io/stage-three/pen/KKGzKdx

As you can see, when you click on "Open SlideOver" only the title is animated and the whole element is rendered. The same applies when you close it by clicking the "x".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this a bit of a read, https://tailwindui.com/documentation#html-transitions.

> We include the recommended transition styles in a comment directly above the dynamic element:

This means that you need to put your alpine transitions in the div directly below the commented part.  I believe you have it in the first div.

Cheers